# MySQL error: Column 'location' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, eclipse, spring-boot

I googled and I haven't been able to find an answer for this. I'm getting the below error from the console in Eclipse. I'm posting my table as well and the DAO, service and controller configuration. If someone can see what my error is please help me understand it. Thanks

```
2020-06-17 09:26:44.859 ERROR 69808 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.p.servers.app.utility.LoggingAspect    : could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'ip_address' cannot be null
```

Table implementation in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE server_tb(
server_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ip_address VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
os_details VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
location VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(server_id)
);




INSERT INTO server_tb(ip_address,os_details,location) VALUES
 ('12.12.89.23','Windows','Palo Alto'),
 ('23.1.23.19','Linux','Palo Alto'),
 ('23.83.48.12','Windows','Texas'),
 ('89.1.2.3','Linux','New Jersey'),
 ('10.2.3.12','Windows','Texas'),
 ('255.255.255.255','Linux','New Jersey'),
 ('231.21.12.38','Linux','New Jersey'),
 ('21.82.231.29','Windows','Palo Alto'),
 ('49.21.34.89','Linux','Texas'),
 ('1.3.89.2','Windows','Palo Alto'),
 ('29.245.21.28','Linux','New Jersey'),
 ('23.123.89.21','Windows','Texas'),
 ('23.89.47.123','Linux','Palo Alto'),
 ('34.21.48.82','Windows','New Jersey'),
 ('84.21.48.23','Linux','Texas'),
 ('112.23.8.2','Windows','New Jersey'),
 ('21.38.29.21','Linux','Palo Alto'),
 ('21.23.42.21','Windows','Texas'),
 ('92.22.48.21','Linux','New Jersey'),
 ('2.32.8.21','Windows','Texas');
```

From DAO

```
@Override
    public void save(Server server) {
        // save or update the server
        Server dbserver = entityManager.merge(server);


        // update with ip address from server

        server.setIpAddress(dbserver.getIpAddress());

    }
```

From Service

```
@Override
    public void save(Server server) throws Exception {
        serverDAO.save(server);

    }
```

From RestController

```
@PostMapping("/save")
    public String saveServer(@ModelAttribute("server") Server server) throws Exception {
        try {
            serverService.save(server);

            return "redirect:/servers/findall";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Error");
        }

    }
```

Server Entity

```
package com.project.servers.app.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="server_tb")
public class Server {

    // define fields
    @Id
    @Column(name="server_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="ip_address")
    private String ipAddress;

    @Column(name="os_details")
    private String osDetails;

    @Column(name="location")
    private String location;

    // define constructors

    public Server() {

    }

    public Server(String ipAddress, String osDetails, String location) {
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
        this.osDetails = osDetails;
        this.location = location;
    }



    public String getIpAddress() {
        return ipAddress;
    }

    public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    }

    public String getOsDetails() {
        return osDetails;
    }

    public void setOsDetails(String osDetails) {
        this.osDetails = osDetails;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Server [ipAddress=" + ipAddress + ", osDetails=" + osDetails + ", location=" + location + "]";
    }



}
```

**UPDATE**

I added default values to my server_tb table and I'm not getting an error anymore but the values are not being saved in the database. All the values are passing as NULL.

Comment: `´server.setIpAddress(dbserver.getIpAddress());` Here you are updating the ipAddress in `server ` (it's a input) rather than `dbserver `

Comment: I removed it but still get the same error